# How exactly is Tally Ho! imbalanced?

Tags: balance

In *[Tally Ho!](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/908/tally-ho)* one player plays the humans (hunters, lumberjacks) while the other plays the animals (foxes, bears). The Dutch rulebook states that since the game is imbalanced, a game is comprised of two hunts, with the players switching sides.

I have played it several times now, but while it's clear that the game is asymmetrical, it isn't clear to me which way the imbalance lies.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Since it's asymmetrical, it's *very* hard to prove that it's balanced. Perhaps they were too lazy to prove it?

Answer (score 4):

The game tends to be much easier for the Hunter player. They have 8 pieces that can kill animals, while the animals only have the 2 bears. Yes, hunters can only attack in a certain direction, but they can move as far as they want, while Bears have to creep up on the hunters.